# Format date string with .000Z into NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I would like to format a date string into a NSDate object, which doesn't sound like a big thing.

The point is, that the date string contains a dot in the timezone value instead of a plus or something else. A date looks like this:

```
2017-06-04T16:00:00.000Z
```

I tried format strings like

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z
```

Of course I've also checked it on [nsdateformatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com), which works but in xCode the NSDate is always nil.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`??

Comment: @Larme Do not quote the `Z`. That's the timezone. When you quote that, the string gets interpreted in local time unless a specific timezone is set on the date formatter. If you don't quote the `Z` there is no need to set a specific timezone on the formatter and the string gets interpreted properly.

Comment: @rmaddy what the meaning of `Z` actually? do you have any reference that I can read into?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This work for me

```
var str = "2017-06-04T16:00:00.000Z"
let formato = DateFormatter()
formato.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
formato.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
formato.formatterBehavior = .default
var data = formato.date(from: str)
```

Comment: There is no need to set the timezone on the formatter. The `Z` in the date string being parsed tells the date formatter what timezone the string represents.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C

```
NSString *strValue = @"2017-06-04T16:00:00.000Z";
NSString *dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

// Or this if you like get in local time
NSString *dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

NSDateFormatter *dateFmtr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFmtr setDateFormat: dateFormat];

// You get a NSDate object
NSDate *dateValue = [dateFmtr dateFromString: strValue];

// Or NSString object
NSString *dateValue = [dateFmtr stringFromDate: dateValue];
```

Other variants for different strings formats.

```
// 2018-02-28T16:38:33.6873197-05:00
// If you have this string format you can use
NSString *strDate1 = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ";
```

For more information with complex formats you can see Patterns
[Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and the Apple's official documentation [Preset Date and Time Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html) and [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem of always getting nils & as a solution you can eliminate the .ZZZZ part from the date String

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let dateString = openningTimeString.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]

let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Comment: A much, much better solution to breaking up the original date string yourself is to simply use the proper date format.