# Date Format for This Type

Tags: ios, swift

What is a Date format for this type of date String :

```
"2017-12-15 07:26:47.977000"
```

Please suggest me which date format used to get this date.

Thanks

Comment: What you have done till now to solve this?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSS"

Comment: https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @Arunsharma did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
 let dateFormattor = DateFormatter()
 dateFormattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
 let date = dateFormattor.date(from: "2017-12-15 07:26:47.977000")
 print("Date \(date)")
```

> 2017-12-15 01:56:47 +0000

Answer (score 0):

I have taken reference form

1. [Format date string with .000Z into NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207286/format-date-string-with-000z-into-nsdate)
2. [iOS Swift 3 : Convert "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" format string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907419/ios-swift-3-convert-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-format-string-to-date-object)

So it same you have to convert in a date object and then transform as per requirement

```
let string = "2017-12-15 07:26:47.977000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print("DATE : \(dateString)")
```